# How to dismiss big view notification after clicking one of its buttons (not the content area)

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have followed Google's tutorial to create a [Big View Styled Notification](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html) (here [their source code](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/training/notify-user/src/com/example/android/pingme)):

[image: screenshot]

in [my own simple test app](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q13/MyNotification/src/de/afarber/mynotification) which displays toasts after clicking on one of the buttons (either in the app or in the big notification):

[image: screenshot]

It works well except for one small problem:

When clicking one of the buttons ("OPEN" or "FLASH") in the notification - I can not see the toast, because it is covered by the black notifications pane.

So my question is: **How to cancel the big notification and close the notifications pane, after I have clicked one of its buttons?** (i.e. not the notification content, but the choice buttons).

Here is my notification building code in [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q13/MyNotification/src/de/afarber/mynotification/MainActivity.java) - there is an `setAutoCancel(true)` call there, but it only works for the content area:

```
Intent openIntent = new Intent(this, RegionService.class);
openIntent.setAction("open");
PendingIntent piOpen = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, openIntent, 0);

Intent flashIntent = new Intent(this, RegionService.class);
flashIntent.setAction("flash");
PendingIntent piFlash = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, flashIntent, 0);

mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle(question)
    .setContentText(question)
    .setTicker(question)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) 
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
         .bigText(question))
    .addAction(R.drawable.open,
        getString(R.string.open_car_short), 
        piOpen)
    .addAction(R.drawable.flash,
        getString(R.string.flash_lights_short), 
        piFlash);
```

Also, I wonder why are the strings "OPEN" and "FLASH" capitalized?

**UPDATE:** I have tried [cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID)](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q14/MyNotification/src/de/afarber/mynotification/RegionService.java) as suggested by Marcin (thanks) and it dismisses the notification, but doesn't close the notification pane. So I still can not see the toasts

Answer (score 2):

You need to cancel this notification from code using NotificationManager's `cancel()`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

Comment: Yes, but my problem is - I do not have access to the NotificationManager/NOTIFY_ID in my service started through the `PendingIntent.getService(...)` - please see my code excerpt above.

Comment: Why? Just get it using `NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)`;

Comment: Yes okay, but the notification id? Should I hardcode it or pass through the intent extra? Or is there a "local way" to get ahold of it? UPDATE: ok, Google [hardcodes](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/training/notify-user/src/com/example/android/pingme/PingService.java) the notification id.

Comment: It's still intent. Attach what you need in its extras (Bundle). Hardcoding usually sucks, no matter who does it. And depending on what is nature of your app sometimes you cannot hardcode it as i.e. it comes from remote API

Comment: So I've tried [cancel](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q14/MyNotification/src/de/afarber/mynotification/RegionService.java) and it dismisses the notification, but doesn't close the notification pane. I still can not see the toasts

Comment: You sure you used right notification Id? It must be the same ID you posted your notification with.

Comment: Yes, I've put the notification id into [CommonConstants.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q14/MyNotification/src/de/afarber/mynotification)

Comment: You need to update your question with more code then

Comment: My complete project is [at GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q14/MyNotification/src/de/afarber/mynotification)

Answer (score 2):

when I was dealing with an issue of dismissing notification one of first solutions I came across and used as a basis is using an activity to receive an intent.

So basically you create an Activity who's whole purpose will be to cancel the notification and "close" the notification drawer.

Bare in mind that this to me seems like an "ugly (but for me pretty cool)" work around. If you found better solution let me know please.

So when you start this activity the notification drawer will be closed automatically as new activity was started. But this activity will be destroyed straight away in onCreate so user will never even see it.

Here's a sample code of the NotificationActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Closes the Notification Drawer
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Cancels the notification
    manager.cancel(getIntent().getIntExtra(CommonConstraints.NOTIFICATION_ID,-1));
    finish();
}
public static PendingIntent getDismissIntent(int notificationId, Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(CommonConstraints.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}
```

As you call finish() in onCreate the Activity will go straight to onDestroy;.

And the getDismissIntent method is used to get the Pending Dismiss Intent in your code when you are creating the notification.

The CommonConstraints is just my class with some static fields.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a little bit late, but you can try this to close the panel.

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
context.sendBroadcast(it);
```